# Pandas dataframe.update with key index, and col index to update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1, which is a rolling dataset I use, updated daily.

I have df2, which contains an id_col and a signal_col. I want to update the signal_cols in df1 based on the common id_col values.

In sql, it would be something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table
SELECT
    COALESCE(my_table_update.signal_col, my_table.signal_col) AS signal_col,
    my_table.*
FROM my_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table_update
ON my_table.id_col = my_table_update.id_col
```

pandas.dataframe.update overwrites the entire dataframe, while
pandas.dataframe.combine_first only adds nulls from df2.

Will I have to iterate over each row, and update the column values manually?

Answer (score 0):

Update only overwrites non na values from right into left.  combine first does the opposite it fills na values in left from right. So update doesn't overwrite the whole frame just non na values